# JPA query using Spring Data is not grouping results

Tags: java, spring-data

I need to group 3 columns of my table with a JPA query but I'm not having success.
It needs to be rendered as follows

```
car   | model | year | color
car1  | model 1 |2020 | black
      | model2  |2021 | red
car 2 | model 7 | 1990 | black
        model 8 | 2005 | red
```

Service:

```
public List<CarDTO> listOrder() {

    List<Object[]> list= CarModelRepository.serachOrder();
    
    var list2 = new ArrayList<CarModel>();
    
    for (Object[] obj : list){
        var car = new Car();
        var model = new Model();
        var carModel = new CarModel();
    
        car = carRepository.findById(Integer.parseInt(obj[1].toString()));
        model = modelRepository.findById(obj[2].toString());
        carModel.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj[0].toString()));
        carModel.setCar(car);
        carModel.setModel(model);
        list2.add(carModel);
    }

    return mapper.listEntityToDTO(list2);
}
```

MyRepository

```
@Repository
public interface CarModelRepository extends JpaRepository<CarModel, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT car.id, car.model.name, car.model.year, car.model.color FROM CarModel car GROUP BY car.id, car.model.name, car.model.year, car.model.color", nativeQuery = false)
    List<Object[]> searchOrder();
   
}
```

Comment: And what is the output you are getting that doesn't match what you expect?

Comment: The output returns all records without grouping by color, year
When run in postman it shows no grouping for example Car 1 returns 2 records in the row without grouping

Comment: Please, post the output of the query. Something like `list.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj.toString()));`  should do.